# how can replace underscore with minus sign in an entire column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list, data-analysis

the picture below is my list where i want to edit two cloumns for future analysis in data cleaning process:
[image: "start_lng" and "end_lng" columns need to be edited]

"start_lng" and "end_lng" columns' content are `dtype('O')` while running the code `Bike_share_data["start_lng"].dtypes`

Now i want to replace underscore (_) with the minus sign (-) and make the entire column dtypes as float.

i have tested a code separately as given below:

```
import pandas as pd
d =[ '_1.0', '_2.0', '_3.0']

d=[s.replace('_','-') for s in d]
print(d)
```

the result is ['-1.0', '-2.0', '-3.0'].

but unable to implement it on Bike_share_data["start_lng"] column. how can i do that?

Comment: you can use `str.replace()` method to replace and then use `astype()` to change the data type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `str.replace()` method to perform the replacement and then use `astype()` to change the data type.

```
# sample DataFrame with a "start_lng" column containing strings
data = {'start_lng': ['_1.0', '_2.0', '_3.0']}
Bike_share_data = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Replace underscores with minus signs & convert the column to float
Bike_share_data["start_lng"] = Bike_share_data["start_lng"].str.replace('_', '-').astype(float)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) and optionally convert the strings to numbers with [`to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [ '_1.0', '_2.0', '_3.0']})

df['start_lng'] = pd.to_numeric(df['start_lng'].str.replace('_', '-'))
```

*If there can be invalid values in the column you can add `errors='coerce'` as parameter to `to_numeric` to ignore them and convert to `NaN`.*

Output:

```
   start_lng
0       -1.0
1       -2.0
2       -3.0
```

Comment: thanx for the addictional information